# Why group calculation fields do not show up in query result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have query like this:
`query = Link.select('url, max(created_at) as created_at, count(*) as url_count').group(:url).order('url_count desc, created_at asc')`

Sample results of `query.results.first`:

```
2.2.0 :002 > query.first
 => #<Link id: nil, url: "http://1", created_at: "2015-03-10 16:43:54">
```

Why there is no `url_count` here, even though I know it is.

```
2.2.0 :003 > query.first.url_count
 => 17
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The count is there all along but the model `to_s` method does not know about it.

The `to_s` method which is used when your console logs the result from `query.first` is defined somewhere in activerecord and it uses the attributes defined for the model in the database. Since your attribute is only defined for this particular instance of `Link` not for the model `Link`.

I found this quite interesting. Below is a description of how the message displayed in your console is constructed. It starts out in the gem `active_attr` with these 3 methods displayed below:

```
def inspect
  attribute_descriptions = attributes.sort.map { |key, value| "#{key}: #{value.inspect}" }.join(", ")
  separator = " " unless attribute_descriptions.empty?
  "#<#{self.class.name}#{separator}#{attribute_descriptions}>"
end

# ...

def attributes
  attributes_map { |name| send name }
end

# ...

def attributes_map
  Hash[ self.class.attribute_names.map { |name| [name, yield(name)] } ]
end
```

the method `attributes_names` is defined in the gem `activerecord`

```
def attribute_names
  @attribute_names ||= if !abstract_class? && table_exists?
      column_names
    else
      []
    end
end

# ...

def column_names
  @column_names ||= @connection.columns(@table_name).collect { |c| c.name }
end
```

And that is why your count does not show up.

If you really want it to show up in your console you could override the `inspect` method and add it there.