# Select with count distinct in ActiveRecord query not returning aggregated fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm doing a select with a count-distinct in ActiveRecord, but it's not returning any of my aggregated fields.

```
User.
  select(
   'users.id, count(distinct(shc.id)) as shipping_credit_count, 
    count(distinct(sc.id)) as service_credit_count'
  ).
  ...
  ...
  group('users.id')
```

Is only returning `#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 119>]>` I was expecting to see the count in my aggregated fields? Why is nothing being returned?

Comment: hey actually it return you a active record you can view your result by as_json seriallizer  `User.
  select('users.id, count(distinct(shc.id)) as shipping_credit_count, 
    count(distinct(sc.id)) as service_credit_count').
  group('users.id').as_json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query probably works as expected but the `inspect` method is throwing you of. Read my answer here for a better description: [Why group calculation fields do not show up in query result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033540/why-group-calculation-fields-do-not-show-up-in-query-result/29046443#29046443)

You should be able to call `service_credit_count` and `service_credit_count` on your objects even though it does not show up when you log them.

I would however implement it a little bit different. I would on the `User` model add the methods

```
def service_credit_count
  return service_credit_count_sql if self.respond_to?(:service_credit_count_sql)
  services.count
end

def shipping_credit_count
  return shipping_credit_count_sql if self.respond_to?(:shipping_credit_count_sql)
  shippings.count
end
```

And then in your query name the fields with the suffix. This way you can always use these counts. There is also a small (quite imature) gem I have written that does this: https://github.com/trialbee/association_count

Comment: Amazing. I wasn't sure anyone was going to answer it. Calling `shipping_credit_count` on the result does the trick. Appreciate you taking the time to answer, thank you very much sir!